# Magento 2 - How to remove an unknown module?

Tags: magento2, module

We have installed a module before and we deleted the module source accidentally. Magento cannot start due to missing module. Is there any way to force uninstall a missing module?

Comment: You have to delete module entry from 'setup_module' table.

Comment: I app/etc/modules of root there will a .xml of that module in that make the tag active to false.

Comment: @Arjun, I think update database is better.

Comment: My comment is use for you or not ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we want to remove a module manually, we can follow these steps:

--Delete the source of this module.

--Go to `setup_module` table to remove our module.

--Remove it in `app/etc/config.php`

--Try to clear Magento Cache, Generation file, `var/composer_home`, `var/view_preprocessed`.

--May delete static content `pub/static/frontend` or `pub/static/adminhtml`, and then run static content again.

Answer (score 1):

I have run this SQL to remove the module manually.

```
delete from setup_module where module = <module name>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you just run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` command then it will remove module from `setup_module` table which currently not available in your app/code folder

Comment: It does not work.